# Lightbox 2 - how to add options

Tags: lightbox2

When I try to use the Lightbox2 options code I get an error saying 'lightbox is not defined'. It works fine when I don't add the option code. What is the correct way to implement the options, the website only has this...

lightbox.option({
      'resizeDuration': 200,
      'wrapAround': true
    })

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#options

Comment: Show us some more code. I doubt you will get a helpful answer this way.

Comment: There is no more code to show - you don't have to explicitly initialise the lightbox in jquery. Once you include the js script then it automatically initialises it - that's why I'm not sure where the option code is meant to go.

Comment: If you're not using AMD, 'lightbox' is set in the global scope. Make sure to call lightbox.options() after the lightbox.js script tag.

Comment: @jk105, Did you solve this issue? I am getting the same error that *lightbox is not defined* and without adding any options to lightbox I am getting this error..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the lightbox options in the file where you include the lightbox.js file. Also please ensure to include jquery before lightbox.

The code below is inside a  block in a php file:

```
    <body>
        ...
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> // <-- this is important
        <script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
        <script>
            lightbox.option({
                'resizeDuration' : 200,
                'wrapAround' : true
            });
        </script>
        ...
    </body>
```

Comment: Yes that's what I'm currently doing and I'm getting the 'Uncaught ReferenceError: lightbox is not defined' error in the js console.

Comment: Yes I'm including jquery as well. This js error is occurring when I add the 'option' code to the demo that I've downloaded from the website - http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started - do you get this error as well? Thanks for your help BTW

Comment: I just downloaded the example from the website and deployed it into my apache. Added the option and it works. I'm using it on a website as well. Can you post the entire html you are using?

Comment: IMHO, the key point here is the you MUST put the options part AFTER the  <script src="js/lightbox.js"></script> directive.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a json error. jsonLint says the json string is not valid. It wants the key names to be quoted (with real quote marks, not appostrophes) like this:

  `lightbox.option({
    "alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices" : true,
    "showImageNumberLabel" : false,
    "wrapAround" : true
});`

Interestingly, it works in some browsers with the appostrophes, and even with no quotes at all, so it's apparently implementation dependent, but the "correct" way apparently is to use quotes (").